# How to get a certain part of a text in python?

Tags: python

I want to extract game id from a steam link "https://store.steampowered.com/app/1307090/Barro_Racing/?snr=1_7_7_230_150_1"
after the `app/` part. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
match = re.findall(r'app/ + /', oyunlink, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: "text".split("app/")[1]

Comment: with that u get everything after the app/ part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u just want the ID(1307090) you can use:

```
x.split("app/")[1].split('/')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
re.search(r'app/(\d+)/', link).group(1)
```